# interacting with screenshare popup in selenium

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Attempting to make a discord screen-share bot, when the share screen button is clicked a popup appears to select witch screen or application to stream.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNimw.png)

It does not appear to be an alert, unsure of how to interact with this as its not embedded within the page source.

sending keystrokes (tab) does not change or select anything within the popup.
doing `switchTo().alert()` results in a not found error.
I haven't found any chrome driver option argument that fixes this issue.

using latest chromedriver version with nodejs.
please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [google-groups](https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/JU6jwFUa5T4/m/qG7mNOuSBAAJ), it seems to be possible using

```py
options.add_argument('--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream')
options.add_argument('--enable-usermedia-screen-capturing')
options.add_argument('--auto-select-desktop-capture-source=Screen 1')
# or "...=Entire screen"
```